# Hibernate lock wait problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling

We have a Java application that listens sockects and records the parsed information to MySql database. We are using hibernate as ORM layer. Whole persistance process is handled by a dedicated thread . Entities are inserted and updated in groups of 20, maximum insert rate is 30 inserts/sec and maximum update rate is 30 updates/sec on a 6-core 24GB-RAM linux box. DB size is around 16GB at the moment. Application hangs after running smoothly for 40 minutes with the exception below :
    `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000
    Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query`

Even if there exists a lock on the row this thread must never stop and if possible forcibly release the lock on the row, how can I guarentee this behaviour? Any help will be appreciated. Below you may find our hibernate configuration:

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://**************:3306/*********?useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=UTF-8;rewriteBatchedStatements=true;includeThreadNamesAsStatementComment=true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <!--Hibernate Batch Process Best Practices -->
  <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="15" />
</properties>
```

Comment: Hi, did you have solved?